# SSH login with secure IP VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, iptables

I have a PC behind a router with port forwarding setup Port 22 for SSH which works perfectly - I can login and everything.  What I am trying to do is let this PC connect to a VPN and only allow traffic on local network or via the VPN connection (for internet access).  This is also working great.  As soon as the VPN connection is broken, the PC has no connection to internet.  Now I am doing this with IPTABLES, the problem is that I can not seem to get incoming SSH to work from external sources via the router port forwarding.  I am thou able to SSH to the pc from within the local network.

Here is what I have tried:

```
# Allow traffic to VPN SERVER
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s $REMOTE_IP -j ACCEPT

# Allow ssh traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT    
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow local traffic.
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT

# Disallow everything else.
sudo iptables -A INPUT ! -i tun+ -j DROP

# Allow traffic from VPN SERVER.
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d $REMOTE_IP -j ACCEPT

# Allow local traffic.
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT

# Disallow everything else.
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT ! -o tun+ -j DROP

sudo openvpn --config client.cfg --auth-user-pass client.cred --daemon
```

Here is my iptables -vL -n output:  (Replaced the vpn server with XX.XX.XX.XX)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 25674 packets, 4792K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
78848   11M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX      0.0.0.0/0           
 3176  318K ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0           
 2517  231K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           
   35 12374 DROP       all  --  !tun+  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 32187 packets, 4374K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3681 2443K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED 
70697   10M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX      
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/8          
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.0.0/12       
   27  5787 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/16      
 2265  150K DROP       all  --  *      !tun+   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

And yes if I do a ifconfig I only have a eth1 and not a eth0 so it is not that.

Here is also the output of netstat -rn

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         XX.XXX.242.128  128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
XX.XXX.193.107  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth1
XX.XXX.242.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
128.0.0.0       XX.XXX.242.128  128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

Comment: When you do `iptables -vL`, do you see any packet count for rules 4, 5, 6 and 9, 10, 11? Anybody from your vpn server has full access to your host. Can you show a `route -n` or `netstat -rn`?

Comment: Okay reran the script without connecting to the openvpn it works so it has got to do with openvpn.

Comment: Then, what's the routing table without openvpn? And what's the openvpn config? How old is your OS? Some have problems with 2 default routes.

Comment: Okay running this (found on some forum I have no idea what is does) makes login from external source work but now the internal ssh login has stopped working.
ip rule add from <internal IP of SSH server/VPN client> table 10
ip route add default via <internal IP of gateway/router> table 10